# Constrained optimization for word2vec giving TypeError

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, mathematical-optimization, word2vec, word-embedding

I want to run [word2vec model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/embedding/word2vec.py) in tensorflow with bounds on embeddings so that they are within unit distance from the origin. That is for every coordinate `x` in Target and Context matrices `-1 <= x <= 1`.

I found this [nice interface](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/opt/ScipyOptimizerInterface) that allows one to do this. However, when I make the changes to the original code, I get the following error.

```
File "/home/sivanov/PycharmProjects/hypemb/tf_word2vec/word2vec_original.py", line 379, in build_graph
    self.optimize(loss)   
File "/home/sivanov/PycharmProjects/hypemb/tf_word2vec/word2vec_original.py", line 297, in optimize
    method = 'SLSQP')
File "/home/sivanov/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/opt/python/training/external_optimizer.py", line 126, in __init__
    self._packed_var = self._pack(self._vars)   
File "/home/sivanov/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/opt/python/training/external_optimizer.py", line 259, in _pack
    return array_ops.concat(flattened, 0)   
File "/home/sivanov/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1066, in concat
    name=name)
File "/home/sivanov/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 493, in _concat_v2
    name=name)
File "/home/sivanov/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 463, in apply_op
    raise TypeError("%s that don't all match." % prefix) TypeError: Tensors in list passed to 'values' of 'ConcatV2' Op have types [float32, float32, float32, int32] that don't all match.
```

So, I [expect](https://github.com/tgjeon/TensorFlow-Tutorials-for-Time-Series/issues/2) that the matrices that I try to bound have mismatch on type. However, I initialize them with uniform distribution, so I'm not sure where I can get `int32` type.

```
emb = tf.Variable(
    tf.random_uniform(
        [opts.vocab_size, opts.emb_dim], -init_width, init_width),
    name="emb")
self._emb = emb

sm_w_t = tf.Variable(
    tf.random_uniform(
        [opts.vocab_size, opts.emb_dim], -init_width, init_width),
    name="sm_w_t", dtype=tf.float32)
self._sm_w_t = sm_w_t
```

In addition to the aforementioned lines, I also added the following snippets:

In `optimize` function:

```
optimizer = tf.contrib.opt.ScipyOptimizerInterface(loss, options={'max_iter': 5}, 
                                                    var_to_bounds = {self._emb: (-1., 1.), self._sm_w_t: (-1., 1.)},
                                                    method = 'SLSQP')
self._optimizer = optimizer
```

In `_thrain_thread_body` function:

```
self._optimizer.minimize(self._session)
```

Full code can be found word2vec code can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_4ijWaHejvBSUpfZ0c0aHdKWUE), and I call this code by running `python word2vec_test.py` (with first pre-compiled word2vec_ops.so file; instructions can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/tutorials/embedding)).

How can I perform optimization of word2vec embeddings with constraints on the coordinates?